# SQL Join With null and duplicate data

Tags: sql

Suppose I have two tables

```
Table1:          Table2:
id valueA        id  valueB 
a  x             a   null
a  y             a   null
```

Tables have duplicate ID's. After I joined both the tables on id my result is

```
id valueA valueB
a  x      null
a  x      null
a  y      null
a  y      null
```

These are the only two columns that are common between the tables and my desire result should be

```
id valueA  valueB
a  x       null
a  y       null
```

Comment: `select id, valueA, valueB from table1` does what you want.

Comment: I did that but  I am getting duplicate rows

Comment: Use `distinct`.

Comment: Can you elaborate in more detail which queries you already tried?

Comment: @MarkusWeninger I just joined the two tables on table1.id=table2.id while selecting id, valueA and valueB

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean with

> Tables have duplicated IDs

since from my point of view IDs should be there to differentiate different entities.

It could be that you are looking for [SELECT DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp), see the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ID, Table1.ValueA, Table2.ValueB FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```